# Working of hashcode() and equals() in java?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

This is the class that we will use to put into a hasmap. It has overriden both `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

```
class Dog
    {
        public String name;
        public Dog(String n)
        {
            name=n;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            System.out.println("in hashcode");
            return name.length();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            System.out.println("in equals");
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Dog other = (Dog) obj;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }


    }
```

This code in main

```
Map<Object,Object> m=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        Dog d1=new Dog("clover");
        m.put(d1,"Dog Key");
        System.out.println(m.get(d1));
```

produces

```
in hashcode
in hashcode
Dog Key
```

but the following code

```
Map<Object,Object> m=new HashMap<Object,Object>();
        Dog d1=new Dog("clover");
        m.put(d1,"Dog Key");
        System.out.println(m.get(new Dog("clover")));
```

produces

```
in hashcode
in hashcode
in equals
Dog Key
```

As you can see there is a call to `equals()` method in the second output. Why is that so?

**My second question** 
If I change the name attribute of the key
Map m=new HashMap();

```
Dog d1=new Dog("clover");
        m.put(d1,"Dog Key");

        d1.name="arthur";
        System.out.println(m.get(new Dog("clover")));
```

the o/p is

```
in hashcode
in hashcode
in equals
null
```

even though I have changed the key value, but I am trying to retrieve the value by giving an identical key. Then why does it retrieve null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question: the `HashMap` needs to call `equals()` to confirm that the two `Dog` objects which both have the same hash code are in fact equal. It doesn't need to call `equals()` the first time because it uses `==` to check for the special case of using the exact same object as previously specified.

For the second question: you changed a data member which changes the calculation of the hash code and the result of `equals()`. This is specifically against the rules, and as a result the map is corrupted; at that point, anything can happen. Never use objects with mutable data for keys in a `HashMap`!

Comment: This reply is already complete. I d like to add some general information on how hashmap work http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because after you put your `d1=new Dog("clover")` into hashmap, you change its name by `d1.name="arthur";` so Dog with name `arthur` is no longer equal to `new Dog("clover")`.

So at first the key hashcode is checked first and it matches as `"clover".length` is equal to `"arthur".length` and this lets identify the bucket where your object is held. After that an `equals()` check is performed to get the right object from the bucket and this fails as your key is not equal to the one provided.

Actually, it is not a good practice to use mutable fields for hashcode calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider how HashMap works.

1. Many objects can have the same hashCode. When do you put an object into the map, it builds a table is based on result of hashCode method. HashMap stores objects with same hashCode in a list and every such list is attached to the table with a cell associated with particular hashCode.
2. When do you get an object from the map, it evaluates a hashCode of a passed key object and then get a list of objects is associated with given hashCode. Then it finds object in the list using equals method.

Using proper hashcode alghorithm and capacity settings for the HashMap allows to reach O(1) performace on put and get in general.

Now lets consider your questions:

1. You go put then get from hashMap. You see a "in equals" statement becuase you have a different object for key. There is a bit of optimisation when keys are the same, HasMap doesn't call equals method in that case. In first case d1 == d1, but d1 != new Dog("clover") for second one.
2. Your objects have the same hashCode but they are no longer equals. And keys are different

But if you change your code in this:

```
Dog d1=new Dog("clover");
    m.put(d1,"Dog Key");

    d1.name="arthur";
    System.out.println(m.get(d1));
```

It should give you atrhur in the end.